# How can you limit the speed of a get request in js?

Tags: javascript

I don’t need to immediately send a request and receive a partial answer. I plan to run the code in the web browser console.  True, I don’t understand if this is even real. That is, it’s probably like this: open a connection and send the header in parts, the same with receiving data. I know how to use Dev Tools, but programmatically in my environment (ZehhoPoster) there is no way to access the tool.

I apologize for the quality of the test, as I am not a native English speaker.

ChatGPT is not able to implement the task, I changed the description of the task, used different versions of them.  The result is always not working, here is the latest code that I managed to get:

```
async function someAsyncFunction() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://site. com');
    const html = await response.text();
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    const parts = [];

    // Split the HTML into 1KB chunks
    for (let i = 0; i < doc.body.childNodes.length; i += 1000) {
      const part = doc.body.childNodes.slice(i, i + 1000);
      parts.push(part);
    }

    // Send each part separately
    const promises = parts.map(async (part) => {
      const partHtml = part.outerHTML;
      const partResponse = await fetch('https://site. com', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: `part=${partHtml}`,
      });
      const partData = await partResponse.text();
      console.log(`Received part ${partData}`);
    });

    // Wait for all promises to resolve
    await Promise.all(promises);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

someAsyncFunction();
```

Comment: I've been working on this problem all day today, but I was assured that "No one from js will give you full low-level control over the request.". But for some reason I’m sure that in js you can send and receive a request with a speed limit.